# Converting PDF to CSV - unexpected argument

Tags: python-3.x, csv, pdf

I have a pdf table that I would like to convert into a csv file. I used [this](https://github.com/data-is-plural/mls-salaries) project which contains already some csvs I want. But unfortunately it does not have the data for 2017, available [here](https://www.mlsplayers.org/images/April%2015,%202017%20Salary%20Information%20-%20By%20Club%20(New%204-26-17).pdf). When using the provided script on every year I get this error:

```
File "convert-pdfs.py", line 54, in <module>
    main()
  File "convert-pdfs.py", line 50, in main
    df = parse_pdf(pdf_path, year)
  File "convert-pdfs.py", line 41, in parse_pdf
    df = pd.concat([ parse_page(page, year) for page in pdf.pages ])
  File "convert-pdfs.py", line 41, in <listcomp>
    df = pd.concat([ parse_page(page, year) for page in pdf.pages ])
  File "convert-pdfs.py", line 29, in parse_page
    table = page.extract_table(v=v, h="gutters", **t)
TypeError: extract_table() got an unexpected keyword argument 'y_tolerance'
```

Does anybody have a clue what can be wrong?

Here is my adapted code for the script, changing only the range of years:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pdfplumber
import pandas as pd
import re
import sys, os

COLUMNS = [
    "club", "last_name", "first_name",
    "position", "base_salary", "guaranteed_compensation"
]

V_SEPARATORS = {
    "narrow": [ 0, 90, 185, 280, 330, 425, 540 ],
    "wide": [ 0, 110, 203, 300, 340, 425, 540 ]
}

NON_MONEY_CHAR_PAT = re.compile(r"[^\d\.]")

def parse_money(money_str):
    stripped = re.sub(NON_MONEY_CHAR_PAT, "", money_str)
    if len(stripped):
        return float(stripped)
    else:
        return None

def parse_page(page, year):
    t = dict(x_tolerance=5, y_tolerance=5)
    v = V_SEPARATORS["narrow" if year == 2007 else "wide"]
    table = page.extract_table(v=v, h="gutters", **t)
    df = pd.DataFrame(table)
    header_i = df[df[0] == "Club"].index[0]
    footer_i = df[df.fillna("").apply(lambda x: "Source" in "".join(x), axis=1)].index[0]
    main = df.loc[header_i + 1:footer_i-1].copy()
    main.columns = COLUMNS
    main["base_salary"] = main["base_salary"].apply(parse_money)
    main["guaranteed_compensation"] = main["guaranteed_compensation"].apply(parse_money)
    return main

def parse_pdf(path, year):
    with pdfplumber.open(path) as pdf:
        df = pd.concat([ parse_page(page, year) for page in pdf.pages ])
    return df

def main():
    HERE = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    for year in range(2007, 2018):
        print(year)
        pdf_path = os.path.join(HERE, "../pdfs/mls-salaries-{0}.pdf".format(year))
        csv_path = os.path.join(HERE, "../csvs/mls-salaries-{0}.csv".format(year))
        df = parse_pdf(pdf_path, year)
        df.to_csv(csv_path, index=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: check `page.extract_table` params. I guess `y_tolerance` isn't a valid parameter.

Comment: It seems like it doesn't take in any of the parameters `TypeError: extract_table() got an unexpected keyword argument 'x_tolerance'` `TypeError: extract_table() got an unexpected keyword argument 'h'` `TypeError: extract_table() got an unexpected keyword argument 'v'`

Comment: Did you try to call the method like this: `page.extract_table(table_settings={})` with settings defined like here: https://github.com/jsvine/pdfplumber#table-extraction-settings

Comment: Yes, it seems like the code is outdated as `Table extraction for pdfplumber was radically redesigned for v0.5.0, and introduced breaking changes.` Have to play with it a bit.